# JavaScript: form refreshing the page, onchange this.form.submit problems

Tags: javascript, database, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

So I have a website that is generated from a database.

each page is a div and the user picks the pages.

When the user chooses a delivery option I have it set so on change it will calculate the cost for them. This is on each page (div).

In Google Chrome this is fine, it submits the page and stays on the page (div) I'm on. When I'm in Firefox or IE it refreshes the page and starts from the beginning page (div).

any ideas?

My code is far too long to post but it is a JQuery plugin which uses divs to make a book. Each page of the book is numbered and has 1 item on it. Then delivery options are in a table and look like this:

```
echo "<td><form method='post' action=''>";
if ($postage != "")
{?>
    <label>
        <select name="postage" id="postage" onchange="this.form.submit()" >
            <option value="UK"<?php echo($postage == 'UK'?' selected="selected"':null) ?>>UK</option> 
            <option value="International"<?php echo($postage == 'International'?' selected="selected"':null) ?>>International</option> 
        </select>
    </label><?php
}
else
{
    ?><label>
        <select name="postage" id="postage" onchange="this.form.submit()" >
            <option>Choose:</option>
            <option value="UK">UK</option>
            <option value="International">International</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <?php
}
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your buttons are like this:

```
<button type="button">a button</button>
```

Comment: You mean `input type='button'`?

Comment: Buttons can have a type set to button, submit, or reset. Submit will submit the form. Reset will reset the form. Button will do nothing unless you give it some Javascript behavior.

Comment: Ignorance on my part, I didn't realize there was a button tag.